# sending email via Post httpclient - Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to send an email via Post more with no results, and it does not generate any error goes through in all processes, is there something wrong with my code?

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var content2 = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content2.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Send")), "templateId");
content2.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Fulano de tal")), "fromName");
content2.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("blablablabal")), "message");
content2.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fulano@tal.com.br")), "fromMail");


using (var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://teste.com.br/Mail/Submit", content2).Result)
{
}
```

Comment: It depends upon what the web API is expecting. Can you use `Postman` to post a new mail to your API? If so, add the `Code` / `Generate Code Snippets` to your question

Comment: You are using http. If this is on iOS, you will need to add ATS exclusions. Try opening the Console app on your Mac and view the simulator logs while the request is being made to find any errors not reported through VS.

Comment: Template error:  error: Error while rendering  "" at line 13 and column 0: &quot;&lt;:sendEmail article=&quot;article&quot; NameValue=&quot;Params.Id&quot; AllowAttachments=&quot;true&quot; /&gt;&quot; -&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: sending by console normally sends, only in the application in C # that is giving this failure